# Weblogic 12c JMS Queue to SAP PI server

Tags: jms, weblogic12c, sap-pi, sap-xi

We are trying to send messages from weblogic 12 JMS Queue (created under JMS module) . But wherever we are putting any message in the queue, SAP PI is not able to read it. It doesn't pop up any error also. However, when SAP PI is sending message to same queue, we are able to receive it in the weblogic queue.

Can anyone help here or suggest any other alternative?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Enrich your answer with your current confg. Deployed drivers, communication channels, etc.

Answer (score 1):

So you deployed the drivers to PI alright? I think you would be best of narrowing it down using XPI Inspector: https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/XI/Tracing+PI+issues+with+XPI+Inspector+tool

I found it very valuable in tracking down errors.